# How to import .dbf with long text values?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to join a .dbf I made in LibreOffice with a shapefile.  The .dbf contains ~10 columns, three of which have a large amount of text (~100 words).

When I import the .dbf into QGIS, all columns appear correctly except for the three with the lengthy text, which instead appear with number values: 0000000001, 0000000003, 0000000005, 0000000007....

Any thoughts on why QGIS is not reading these values correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the text datatype, length is limited by the dbf format to 65534 characters. Exceeding this would cause QGIS to react strangely. Check this first. In ArcGis (sorry, don't know about QGIS), the text field length is typically max 254.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Marketa is right: quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase): A second filetype is the .dbt file format for memo fields. While character fields are limited to 254 characters each, a memo field is a 10-byte pointer into a .dbt file which can include a much larger text field. But: the shapefile-format and therefore qgis  cant use this dbt-files! BTW: When you try to export a a file to dbf in the actual libreoffice and a text record contains more chars than 254 you get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I guess LO takes the field defnition (FIELDNAME,N,19,11) and adds leading zeros according to the definition (11 after the comma), but; as a comma also gets added, the total number of digits becomes 20 instead of 19 ,and thus consideres the number of digits as too long.